# Download Apple-issued certificates via API

Tags: ios, certificate, x509certificate, apple-developer

I have an Apple Developer account, can I generate a p12 certificate by calling the API for Apple-issued certificates? I know that I can now download the certificate directly through the Apple website, but I wonder if I can download the certificate by calling the api?

Thanks!